# Calculated columns supporting all column types

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, managed-metadata, people-picker, calculated-column

I would like to develop a column which will allow the end user to do the calculations based on values of other columns of the same item (SharePoint 2010). I need it to work also with people, look up and managed metadata columns so that's why I can't use calculated column. I was thinking about custom field and event handler but custom fields won't work with content type hub, which is required in my project. How should I approach this problem?